# how can I make function of another contract callable?

Tags: remix, contract-debugging

Obviously there is a problem with the deploy procedure or the remix IDE, but how can I make the function callable?

```
pragma solidity> = 0.5.0 <0.6.0;

import'openzeppelin-solidity / contracts / math / SafeMath.sol';

contract TestContract {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    mapping (address => uint256) private balance;
    mapping (address => bool) private accountBook;
    
    modifier checkPoint () {
        require (accountBook [msg.sender], "You need to have an account with us");
        _;
    }
    
    modifier alreadyExists () {
        require (! accountBook [msg.sender], "You are already an account holder");
        _;
    }
    function createAcc () public alreadyExists () {
        accountBook [msg.sender] = true;
    }
    
    function deposit () public payable checkPoint () {
        require (msg.value> 0, "Please send some funds");
        balance [msg.sender] = balance [msg.sender] .add (msg.value);
    }
    
    function closeAccount () public checkPoint () {
        require (balance [msg.sender]> 0, "You dont have any balance");
        address (msg.sender) .call.value (balance [msg.sender]) ("");
        accountBook [msg.sender] = false;
        balance [msg.sender] = 0;
    }

}

contract CallFunc {
    TestContract public testcontract;
    address public addr;
    
    constructor (address _addr) public payable {
        testcontract = TestContract (addr);
        addr = _addr;
    }
    
    function preset () public {
        testcontract.createAcc ();
        
    }
```

By the way, even if the amount of gas was set to 60 gwei, it did not work.
The same behavior occurs with javascriptVM and injected web3.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the constructor you are assigning `addr` instead of `_addr` (with underscore prefix) to `testcontract`.

After fixing that it works

```
constructor (address _addr) public payable {
    testcontract = TestContract(_addr);
    addr = _addr;
}
```